# ¿Cómo mejorar una pregunta para evitar los votos negativos?

Tags: discusión, pregunta-específica, votos-negativos

Tengo un problema de programación y ando buscando soluciones, hasta la fecha varias ideas pero ninguna se me ajusta. Bueno, pues voy yo y pongo una pregunta en la comunidad, explicando lo que he investigado y lo que he hecho, la trayectoria y el por qué hago las cosas, dando un poco de background al lector a ver si me puede ayudar. La pregunta es [CommandManager.RequerySuggested equivalente en .NET Standard 2.0?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/336819/commandmanager-requerysuggested-equivalente-en-net-standard-2-0).

Yo creo que la pregunta está bien formulada, pero sorprendentemente, me dan un voto negativo, y digo yo ¿por qué? no hay ningún comentario al respecto que ayude a mejorar la pregunta.

No veo el motivo del voto negativo, y me parece que la pregunta es pertinente, entonces digo yo, ¿no deberíamos bloquear los negativos sin explicación?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Los votos, tanto positivos como negativos, son anónimos. Pedir una explicación a cualquier tipo de voto sería romper ese anonimato y entiendo que no es algo que se busque.

Por otro lado el voto es algo subjetivo y el uso de los mismos depende de cada usuario: hay gente que vota más, gente que vota menos; gente que es más exigente con los positivos, gente que es más prudente con los negativos.

En resumen: creo que no podemos hacer nada al respecto que no rompa con la idea de "automoderación" del sitio, aparte de intentar compensar lo que consideremos un voto injusto con el nuestro. En tu caso, ya que no se puede votar una publicación propia, simplemente ten paciencia y deja que otros usuarios aporten más *feedback*.

Answer (score 6):

Tu pregunta tiene, **a mi juicio**, varios problemas de formato. Para ir al grano, **tu verdadera pregunta** está al final del todo:

> Así que estoy abierta a soluciones: alguien sabe del equivalente en .NET Standard de CommandManager.RequerySuggested? Es lo único que se me ha ocurrido de momento.

Eso está claramente **basado en opiniones**.

Continando un poco mas ... ciertamente, das detalles ... ah no, perdona: **mandas a los usuarios a que visiten enlaces externos** para poder seguir tu pregunta.

Deberías concretar bastante mas y mostrar el **código exacto** que te está dando el problema, a ser posible, con un ejemplo verificable.

<sub>Nota: el -1 no es mio</sub>

Comment: Creo que el hecho de que coloques todo ese feedback aquí hace innecesaria la nota ;)

Comment: Vamos a ver, varias cosas: 1.- no hay necesidad de ser borde. 2.- no entiendo por qué dices que está basado en opiniones, pregunto claramente si alguien sabe de alguna clase, propiedad,... built in, o sea que haga lo mismo y que esté incluida en .NET Standard 2.0, a veces las cosas cambian de nombre, y lo sé porque he traducido mucho código de vb.net antiguo a .NET Standard 2.0, pregunto claramente si esto es el caso, no es una opinión lo que busco.

Comment: La pregunta es clara, busco el equivalente a CommandManager.RequerySuggested, que esté disponible en .NET Standard 2.0, si quieres ir a los enlaces por tu propio beneficio ve, pero no creo que sea imprescindible para entender la pregunta. En cuanto al código exacto, feedback noted, puesto pero no creo que aporte mucho a la pregunta, ya que esta es muy concreta

Comment: @Iria Si tan claro lo tienes, no se para que preguntas aquí ... esta es mi opinión. Tengo +4, por lo que al menos otros 4 usuarios piensan igual o parecido a mi.

Comment: he incluido los comentarios que me han parecido, si te fijas, he incluido código, igual si planteo la pregunta de otra manera, (eliminando cosas en plan, tengo este codigo y falla por aqui, hay algun equivalente en .NET STandard 2.0?) será mejor aceptada, una vez vistos tus comentarios, pero he querido dar un poco más de info, el vídeo que seguía y demás por si le resulta útil a alguien. A mi me es dificil encontrar videos buenos

Comment: @Iria Preguntar __alguien sabe__ debería estar mal visto, es mejor preguntar, __¿Cuál es el equivalente?__